# JavaScript: How to remove the duplicate entries from array with respect to multiple keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have an array like this:

```
0: {ClusterId: "10.210.28.231", Device IP: "10.210.28.231", SlotID: "1"}
1: {ClusterId: "10.210.28.234", Device IP: "10.210.28.234", SlotID: "1"}
2: {ClusterId: "10.210.28.231", Device IP: "10.210.28.231", SlotID: "2"}
3: {ClusterId: "10.210.28.234", Device IP: "10.210.28.234", SlotID: "2"}
4: {ClusterId: "10.210.28.234", Device IP: "10.210.28.234", SlotID: "2"}
5: {ClusterId: "10.210.28.231", Device IP: "10.210.28.231", SlotID: "2"}
```

I am trying to remove the duplicates by both `ClusterId` and `SlotID`. Below is my sample code where I am pushing the duplicate values into one array (`duplicateArrayVal`) and non-duplicates to other array (`importArrayVal`)

```
UniqueArraybyObject($scope.excelRowArray, "SlotID", "ClusterId");

function UniqueArraybyObject(collection, slotId, clusterName) {
    var importArrayVal = [],
        slot = [],
        clusters = [];

    $scope.duplicateArrayVal = [];
    angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
        var tempSlot = item[slotId];
        var cluster = item[clusterName];
        if ((slot.indexOf(tempSlot) === -1) || (clusters.indexOf(cluster) === -1)) {
            slot.push(tempSlot);
            clusters.push(cluster);
            importArrayVal.push(item);
        } else {
            $scope.duplicateArrayVal.push(item);
        }
    });

    return importArrayVal;
};
```

The problem that occurs for me is items at 3,4 and 5 rows are not displaying as these are considered as duplicates. But only the 4 and 5th row will be the duplicate one and not the 3th. I need the 3th row to be in non-duplicate array.

Please help me to achieve this

Comment: why 3rd will not consider as duplicate? what logic you are thinking for that? it clearly seen that 3rd one is duplicate of 1st

Comment: 1st is with SlotID:1 whereas the 3rd with SlotID:2. i need to check for both the keys

Comment: then it will be applied for all, and then you will not treat 2 as duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once solution would be to construct an intermediate `map` where:

- the key of `map` is a compound key from the `ClusterId` and `SlotID` values of each item in the input array and
- the value is the last item encountered in the input array for that key

After building a `map` in this way, you'll have a set of values that are unique by the `ClusterId` and `SlotID` item values. The resulting `map` can then be passed to `Object.values()` to obtain the unique item values as an array:

```js
const data=[
{'ClusterId':"10.210.28.231",'Device IP':"10.210.28.231",'SlotID':"1",'Actions':"Assign"},
{'ClusterId':"10.210.28.234",'Device IP':"10.210.28.234",'SlotID':"1",'Actions':"Assign"},
{'ClusterId':"10.210.28.231",'Device IP':"10.210.28.231",'SlotID':"2",'Actions':"Assign"},
{'ClusterId':"10.210.28.234",'Device IP':"10.210.28.234",'SlotID':"2",'Actions':"Assign"},
{'ClusterId':"10.210.28.234",'Device IP':"10.210.28.234",'SlotID':"2",'Actions':"Assign"},
{'ClusterId':"10.210.28.231",'Device IP':"10.210.28.231",'SlotID':"2",'Actions':"Assign"}
];

/* Reduce input array to a map (see following description), and then
  extract map values as array to obtain final result */
const result = Object.values(data.reduce((map, item) => {

  /* Build a map of values where with a compound key derived from the
     ClusterId and SlodID field values */
  return { ...map,
    [`${ item.ClusterId }-${ item.SlotID }`]: item
  };

}, {}))

console.log(result);
```

#### Update

If compatibility with older browsers is a requirement, the following will achieve the same result without dependence on newer ES6 syntax:

```js
var data=[
{'ClusterId':"10.210.28.231",'Device IP':"10.210.28.231",'SlotID':"1",'Actions':"Assign"},{'ClusterId':"10.210.28.234",'Device IP':"10.210.28.234",'SlotID':"1",'Actions':"Assign"},{'ClusterId':"10.210.28.231",'Device IP':"10.210.28.231",'SlotID':"2",'Actions':"Assign"},{'ClusterId':"10.210.28.234",'Device IP':"10.210.28.234",'SlotID':"2",'Actions':"Assign"},{'ClusterId':"10.210.28.234",'Device IP':"10.210.28.234",'SlotID':"2",'Actions':"Assign"},{'ClusterId':"10.210.28.231",'Device IP':"10.210.28.231",'SlotID':"2",'Actions':"Assign"}
];


var map = {};
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var item = data[i];
  map[item.ClusterId + "-" + item.SlotID] = item;
}

var result = [];
for(var k in map) {
  result.push(map[k]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: can this be done in javascript or angular instead of Es6